# Strict Filter Array of Arrays

Tags: javascript, angularjs, indexof, angularjs-filter

I have a tags input box, [similar to this](http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/) except I need to restrict it to allowable combinations.

Here is an example of the possible combinations:

```
[{
      "Combo": [
        {
          "Id": 1,
          "Name": "Tag1"
        },
        {
          "Id": 3,
          "Name": "Tag3"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Combo": [
        {
          "Id": 2,
          "Name": "Tag2"
        },
        {
          "Id": 3,
          "Name": "Tag3"
        },
        {
          "Id": 4,
          "Name": "Tag4"
        }
      ]
    }]
```

I start off by getting a distinct list of Tags and displaying them to the user. As tags are selected, I need to filter the tags by the passed combinations. Therefore, if I select Tag3, I should get the available tags of Tag1, Tag2 & Tag4. I was able to accomplish this by looping through the array of arrays and getting the index of the combos by the array of ids. Like so:

```
ids.indexOf(combos[a].Combo[c].Id) !== -1
```

However the issue is when I then add Tag2 to the array of ids, indexOf still includes the first combo because of the Id: 3. What I want is to find the combos that have matching or more Ids.

So when I pass this:

```
var ids = [3, 2];
```

I want this combo:

```
[{
      "Combo": [
        {
          "Id": 2,
          "Name": "Tag2"
        },
        {
          "Id": 3,
          "Name": "Tag3"
        },
        {
          "Id": 4,
          "Name": "Tag4"
        }
      ]
    }]
```

It is a bit messy, but here is the jsfiddle example I have been working on. http://jsfiddle.net/4L3kr052/

Comment: Can you elaborate on "I need to filter the tags by the passed combinations."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a fiddle solving this problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/4L3kr052/1/

```
var getAvailableTags = function (combos, ids) {
        var matched = []
        combos.forEach(function(comb){
            var keys = comb.Combo.map(function(d){
                return d.Id;
            }); 
            var found = 1;
            ids.forEach(function(id){
                found &= (keys.indexOf(id) !== -1);
            });
            if (found){
                matched.push(comb);
            }

        })
        return matched;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solve one problem at a time,

### First,

How to test a *Combo* for every *id*? Move the logic to test this into it's own function to make your life easier, for example

```
function comboHasIds(combo, ids) {
    var i, j;
    find_next: for (i = 0; i < ids.length; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < combo.length; ++j)
            if (combo[j].Id === ids[i])
                continue find_next;
        return false; // if we reach here then id[i] wasn't in combo
    }
    return true; // if we reach here then we ran out of ids to test for
}
```

*Please notice the use of a [**label**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) to let the nested loop [`continue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue) the outer loop*

Example usage on a single *Combo* is as follows

```
var ex = [
        {"Id": 2, "Name": "Tag2"},
        {"Id": 3, "Name": "Tag3"},
        {"Id": 4, "Name": "Tag4"}
    ];

comboHasIds(ex, [3, 1]); // false
comboHasIds(ex, [3, 2]); // true
```

---

As [zerkms](https://stackoverflow.com/users/251311/zerkms) [**points out**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33747995/strict-filter-array-of-arrays/33748132#comment55264886_33748132), as does [**Adeel's answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33748283/1615483), this test is of the form

1. For *every* `id`
2. If there is *some* item in `combo`
3. Which has *Id* property `id`
4. Return `true`

Which could be written using *`Array.prototype` methods* [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead of nested loops, e.g. as one line in [*arrow functions*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```
var comboHasIds = (combo, ids) => ids.every(id => combo.some(item => item.Id === id));
```

---

### Second,

How to iterate over each *Combo* with this test? We have the handy [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method just for this, so filtering with the above would look like

```
// var data = /* your data from above */;
var test = function (ids) {
        return function (e) {return comboHasIds(e.Combo, ids);};
    };

data.filter(test([3, 2]));
// [{"Combo": [
//   {"Id": 2,"Name": "Tag2"},
//   {"Id": 3,"Name": "Tag3"},
//   {"Id": 4, "Name": "Tag4"}
// ]}]
```

Comment: They said "to make your life easier" and then used labels and goto-like `continue`. That's funny :-)

Comment: @zerkms would you prefer I wrote "for example"? The key point of this answer is that OP can break the big problem down into two smaller problems which individually are easier to solve.

Comment: Don't know the exact better wording, the whole function just looks too tangled even for example. PS: es2015 oneliner: `ids.every(id => combo.some(c => c.id === id))`

Comment: @zerkms edited it to show this alternative way. Seriously though, is using `break` or `continue` that advanced? You haven't learnt loops if you haven't learnt them. I can understand labels being new to some people, though. They will probably become more used now ES6 `let` has block scope.

Comment: it's not `continue` or `break` that problematic, but unconditional jumps.

Answer (score 0):

To get the required combos, you need to `filter` them such that the given combo contains every id from the `ids` array.

```
var combos = [{
      "Combo": [
        {
          "Id": 1,
          "Name": "Tag1"
        },
        {
          "Id": 3,
          "Name": "Tag3"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Combo": [
        {
          "Id": 2,
          "Name": "Tag2"
        },
        {
          "Id": 3,
          "Name": "Tag3"
        },
        {
          "Id": 4,
          "Name": "Tag4"
        }
      ]
    }];

function getCombos(combos, ids) {
    return combos.filter( // filter accepts combos that...
        function (g) {
            return ids.every( // ... contain every id in ids...
                function (id) {
                    return g.Combo.some( // ... such that the id is present within some combo.
                        function (c) {
                            return c.Id === id;
                        });
                });

        });
}

getCombos(combos, [3, 2]); // returns your desired combo
getCombos(combos, [3, 1]); // returns the first combo
getCombos(combos, [3, 5]); // returns an empty array
```